# jQuery hiding all instead of just the not active

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm currently running a script that grabs images from a folder and displays them in a slideshow. (this has had to be done in a certain way due to compatibility with ie8 and 9.)

Due to how I'm avoiding the aspect ratio being stretched the images are appearing behind the smaller images so you can see all the being stacked rather than just one image visible.

I tried using

```
 $('.image-container img:not(active)').css('display','none');
```

but it instead hides all the images rather than show the active one.

I also tried to use padding on the images but because I don't know what the size of the images are adding a border / padding to each one with a background of #FFF means the smaller images are still not block out the larger ones.

my slider JS

```
$.fn.slider = function (interval) {
    var slider = this;

    setInterval(function () {
        var $active = $(slider).find(".active");
        if ($active.length == 0) {
            $active = $(slider).find("IMG:last");
        }
        var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $(slider).find("IMG:first");
        $active.addClass('last-active');
        $next.css({
                opacity: 0.0
            })
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, 1000, function () {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            });
    }, interval);
}
```

PHP

```
div class="activelink scrollLink" id="link-9">
                            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/img/blankframe.png" alt="">
                          <div class="slideshow" id="slide7">
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <?php 
                                    $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/../../customImg/');
                                    while($file = readdir($handle)){
                                       if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                                           echo '<img src="' . Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl . '/customImg/'.$file.'" border="0" />';
                                        }
                                    }
                                 ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
.image-container{
    display: block;
    max-width: 205px;
    max-height: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 90% 5% 10% 5%;
    top:-310px;
    left:13%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    background-size:800px;
}

.image-container img{
  display: block;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#FFF;
  border-radius:5px;
}

div.activelink#link-9 img{
  width:260px;
}

div.activelink#link-9{
  background-color:#FFF;
  height:320px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed `.` of `active`

```
$('.image-container img:not(.active)').css('display','none');
//                          ^
```

**EDIT**

Using `not`:

```
$('.image-container img').not('.active').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Still no luck, it's still hiding the active.

Comment: Yep, I would have thought that would have worked too but it's still not displaying any images. Surely it should be ignoring the active class.

Comment: @Alex Can you please create jsfiddle of the same